# C# Count Items across an Array of Lists

Tags: c#, arrays, linq

I am new to C#.  I have an array of lists that looks something like this:

```
var baskets = [
[apples, oranges, peaches],
[oranges, grapes, bananas],
[oranges, grapes, apples]
[bananas, strawberries, peaches]
]
```

I need to turn it into a single array with a count of each fruit like this:

```
   var fruitCount = [
{fruit: apples , count:2},
{fruit: oranges, count: 3},
{fruit: peaches, count: 2},
{fruit: grapes, count: 2},
{fruit: bananas, count: 2},
{fruit: strawberries, count: 1}]
```

I was looking at `LINQ's` "`.SelectMany`" but it just seems to flatten out the array into one list.  I honestly don't know how to begin.  Can anyone point me to a code sample that could help?

Comment: first flatten and then do `group by`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
var result = baskests.SelectMany(x => x)
    .GroupBy(x => x)
    .Select(x => new { 
        Fruit = x.Key, 
        Count = x.Count() 
    });
```

This does exactly what Rahul suggested in the comment. It first flattens all fruits into one single list containing duplicates and than groups the list. Finally the `Select`-statement will create an anonymous instance for every group having a `Fruit`- and a `Count`-property.

Comment: @RenéVogt Well, as OP posted only some psueod-code I assumed he had a property for the fruits- which apparently does not.

Answer (score 1):

You need to flatten the array with `SelectMany` and then group the entries:

```
var flattened = baskets.SelectMany(basket => basket);
var fruitCount = flattened.GroupBy(fruit => fruit, 
                                   (fruit, g) => new { fruit, count = g.Count()});
```